# Enable custom error message in Azure app service (Spring boot application)

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I have a custom error message for authorization failure in a spring boot application, it works fine in localhost but when deployed in azure it returns like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": TIMESTAMP,
    "status": 401,
    "error":"unauthorized",
    "message": "unauthorized",
    "path": "/testapplication"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no such feature to have custom error messages in azure App Services. There has been a [feature request planned](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32128597-allow-for-customized-error-messages-in-azure-ad-co?page=2&per_page=20) for this. You can make a follow up comment on it from there or you can give a feed back [HERE](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/905242-update-management) for feature request.

Check the below threads for related conversations.

1. [Spring Oauth2 returns 401 Unauthorized error with spring boot 2.0 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564009/spring-oauth2-returns-401-unauthorized-error-with-spring-boot-2-0)
2. [java - Spring Security - 401 Unauthorized for token end point (/oauth/token) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490088/spring-security-401-unauthorized-for-token-end-point-oauth-token)
3. [java - Spring Boot 2.0.3 Oauth2 Security: Getting 401 error even when using access token in header - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823052/spring-boot-2-0-3-oauth2-security-getting-401-error-even-when-using-access-toke)